# Is Redhat moving away from HornetQ to ActiveMQ?

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, redhat, hornetq

HornetQ, the open source Message implementation created by RedHat is promoted as part of RedHat's JBoss Application Server. HornetQ was a strong contender for ApacheMQ when it was initially launched.

I was going through JBoss Fuse documentation and realized that "Active MQ" is used as Messaging technology. (I know that JBoss Fuse is developed on Apache Camel)

My question is, "Is RedHat Moving away from HornetQ? or It will use both implementations in their products?". I have not seen any official announcement about replacing "HornetQ" with "ActiveMQ", but wanted to find out their steps.

I have been using "HorntQ" as it is native to JBoss, because of the arrival of many new components to my project, I am looking to adopt Jboss Fuse as an ESB. And observed the major difference in messaging systems.

As we used JMS, I hope there will not be a major changes required for my Queue/Factory/Messaging related config. For any new applications developed using JBoss, is it recommended to use ActiveMQ than HornetQ?

Comment: Hi, HornetQ is still under active development at Red Hat and it's a safe bet for current and future deployments.

Best regards,
Dave.
Engineering Manager for Red Hat's messaging technologies.